# Cut a directory?

Tags: groovy

Is there a method to cut a directory/file in groovy instead of copyingto a new location and then deleting the original directory/file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `move` a file?

You can do:

```
File file = new File( 'original.txt' )  
File dir = new File( 'destFolder' )  
boolean fileMoved = file.renameTo( new File( dir, file.getName() ) )
```

Which uses the [Java File.renameTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) method